# I am having trouble adding HTML5 (background colours and colours) to my website within the WordPress editor

Tags: wordpress, html

Here is a list of the research that I have done. First I looked how to do it on the internet and I found [this site](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Text-Color-in-HTML).

Then I asked a friend and he suggested that I do this with the code, and as an example, gave this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

so in HTML

```
<h1 class"best-header-ever"> Header </h1>
```

then in CSS

```
.best-header-ever {
color: blue;}
```

I don't know if he was doing it in the right order so the above, is the most information I have of an alternative strategy

Now I am working on this, again in the WordPress editor:

```
.best-header-ever{color: blue;}


<header> header
link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href=styles.css

[header/]
```

(this text to the left was part of the website-->)This is a contact page with some basic contact information and a contact form.

```
[contact-form]<span id="mce_SELREST_start" style="overflow:hidden;line-
height:0;"></span>[contact-field label="Name" type="name" required="1"/]
[contact-field label="<span id="mce_SELREST_start" 
style="overflow:hidden;line-height:0;"></span> Email" type="email" 
required="1"/][contact-field label="Website" type="url"/][contact-field 
label="Comment" type="textarea" required="1"/][/contact-form]

body/
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I would like to add background colour to the font and text. Oh, I have also been working on freecodecamp.org as research.

I am trying to learn how to do this work without the security net of freecodecamp to improve my skills.

Also, I don't know if I can even add HTML5 to HTML (everything from contact form to /contact form was being registered by the computer, but when I added any other characters, no background colours or colours would display).

This is what the page looks like:

[myedit_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/astNO.jpg)

I don't know if this makes a difference, but the WordPress editor has buttons:

[wordpress-editor-interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrkXF.jpg)

Comment: Dear Sir. There is a specific way you include style sheets in WordPress. This is a suggestion and it may be correct, incorrect, or incomplete: "You will want to start here https://developer.wordpress.org/ where you will find all you need to know. You will also benefit from reading the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/. Also, refrain from using the editor for changes, rather use version control ( git ) with a local development environment." from free code camp capetown

Comment: Just asking for clarification on what you mean with git; is this what you mean? see below. the website does not explain  gits role...is it just to test code? https://developers.squarespace.com/using-git Just asking for clarification about your suggestion to make sure I follow community guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `background-color:` instead of `color:`. Color will just change the text color, or the color of the words inside that header. Using `background-color` will change the background color.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but this does not do anything. I appreciate the time and effort that you put into your answer. However, I am still having the same issue that the output does not present on the page. Like I said, I am trying to create my online portfolio, so please don't mark my post as spam. or email me the reason why if you do.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your initial question:

When you assign a class in HTML, make sure to put an equals sign between 'class' and the name of the class in quotes:

This:
`<h1 class"best-header-ever"> Header </h1>`

Becomes:
`<h1 class="best-header-ever"> Header </h1>`

Also, to address your issue about how to learn and test your code, I suggest using something like jsfiddle.net.  You can test HTML, CSS, and Javascript (when you are ready for that) and see the results live.